# Does Excel round up a number automatically?

Tags: excel

The value in cell A2 is 20.64907652 and I have put a formula in B2 which is **=A2** but get the value in B2 as 20.65 and I cannot increase the decimals.  Is **=Round(A2,10)** the only way? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want B2 to be 20.65907652 or 20.65? If you need 20.65 just use Round(A2,2).

Comment: Can't you just format the cell?

Comment: Right click column b, select format cells. Ensure "general" is selected

Comment: [Video: Show and hide decimal places in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Show-and-hide-decimal-places-in-Excel-37C1F77A-F3DF-43FF-9D90-36B7F09C3741)

Comment: Why is this a VBA question? `=A2` looks like a formula to me.

Answer (score 0):

For number comparisons like this I like to show the explicit "rounding" that you're doing directly in the comprison, like so:

```
=If(ABS(A1-B2)<.02,"Close Enough","Not Equal")
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two more formulas :
- =ROUNDUP(A2;2)
- =ROUNDDOWN(A2;2)

I hope this help.